# What does .read() actually do, and what gets returned when it .read() is not used?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, byte

I how to use it but I noticed that if I don't use read then it can spit out different thing.

It can spit out `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='story.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>`
 when using text files.

It can also return `<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x76521550>`
 when using urlopen from urllib.
What do those things mean and what does .read() actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are "file-like objects" that have a `.read()` method and you are seeing the `repr()` of the object, which is a description string.  When you call `.read()` it reads the complete contents from the object, usually as a byte or Unicode string.

A small, custom example:

```
class Demo:
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<My Custom Description>'
    def read(self):
        return 'some stuff'

x = Demo()
print(x)
print(x.read())
```

Output:

```
<My Custom Description>
some stuff
```

Comment: Thanks! But do you know what the one with the http means?

Comment: @WilliamStern It's still a file-like object.  In that case, wrapping the response stream from an http socket. `.read()` reads the socket until it closes and returns the result as a string.